# Watch Flash video but block out part of it

Tags: linux, mac, flash-player, subtitles, fullscreen

I'm learning a foreign language.  There are several online sites that have Flash video in the language I'm learning (e.g., Hulu), which is great.  Unfortunately, they have English subtitles, which is (depending on who you ask) somewhere between "annoying" and "actively harmful to my learning".

When I'm watching them in a window, I can just move them near the bottom of the screen, or put another window over them.  That's awkward, but it kind of works.

But I'd like to watch them full-screen, on my TV set.  Full-screen Flash doesn't let me put any window on top of it.

Is there a way to watch an online Flash video but block out part of it?

I'll probably be using my Mac for this, but maybe Linux -- solutions for either one welcome.

Answer (score 6):

How about a Post-It note? No, seriously. It's relocatable, cross-platform and always on top :)

Comment: I was going to suggest duct tape (two out of three ain't bad). However, I'm assuming his TV is big enough that it would take several Post-Its, so advantage duct tape!

Comment: Well, my TV isn't *that* big, but I was hoping for a software solution rather than a hardware solution.  :-)

Comment: +1 for the duct tape. I understand you'd like a software solution. But if you don't find any, duct tape is probably the best way to go. It's cheap, quick, and won't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Some linux desktop environments actually allows you to set any window to be "always on top". I haven't tested how it interacts with full-screen flash videos (my linux box isn't with me right now). I'f you haven't tried it out yet, just right-click the window title and select "Always on Top".

If you have tried it out, and it doesn't work, just ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, the Keyboard Viewer and Character Viewer, if displayed, will appear over full-screen Flash and can be used to obscure the subtitles.  If you don't already have these in your menu bar, go to System Preferences » Keyboard, and check the box in they Keyboard pane.